# Error using Let's Encrypt in Ingress:Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist using

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt, minikube

I followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes to issue a SSL certificate for my ingress using cert manager and Let's encrypt and I run this error  `Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist`. Is my configuration wrong? It's a Minikube local cluster.

staging_issuer.yaml

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
 name: letsencrypt-staging
 namespace: cert-manager
spec:
 acme:
   # The ACME server URL
   server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
   # Email address used for ACME registration
   email: email_address
   # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
   privateKeySecretRef:
     name: letsencrypt-staging
   # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
   solvers:
   - http01:
       ingress:
         class:  nginx
```

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "12h"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - frontend.info
    - backend.info
    secretName: echo-tls
  rules:
  - host: frontend.info
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
  - host: backend.info
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: backend
          servicePort: 8080
```

kubectl describe certificate

```
Name:         echo-tls
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1beta1
Kind:         Certificate
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-01-26T09:29:54Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    Manager:    controller
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2021-01-26T09:29:55Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           extensions/v1beta1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Ingress
    Name:                  echo-ingress
    UID:                   <UID>
  Resource Version:        423812
  UID:                     <UID>
Spec:
  Dns Names:
    frontend.info
    backend.info
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:      cert-manager.io
    Kind:       ClusterIssuer
    Name:       letsencrypt-staging
  Secret Name:  echo-tls
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2021-01-26T09:29:54Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Issuing
    Last Transition Time:        2021-01-26T09:29:54Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      False
    Type:                        Ready
  Next Private Key Secret Name:  echo-tls-hg5tt
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From          Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----          -------
  Normal  Issuing    7h56m  cert-manager  Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
  Normal  Generated  7h56m  cert-manager  Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "echo-tls-hg5tt"
  Normal  Requested  7h56m  cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "echo-tls-hmz86
```

Comment: Have you gone thru all the prerequisites from that documentation? How did you setup your domains? Why do you consider this as an error? This does not look like a blocking issue to me.

Comment: I followed the same tutorial with the same outcome. I then followed the tutorial at https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/ingress/ successfully which is more up-to-date. Take special note of the difference in the resource kind for the issuers - DO's tutorial uses kind: ClusterIssuer vs cert-manager's kind: Issuer.

Answer (score 5):

Let' start from answering your question about the event:

```yaml
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From          Message
  Normal  Issuing    7h56m  cert-manager  Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
```

This is not an error and it is not a blocking factor. As you can see in the `type` section this is marked as `Normal`.  The events type that you should worry about are `Warning` events, like here:

```yaml
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From                                                    Message
  Warning  Unhealthy  2m (x2 over 2m)    kubelet, ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal  Readiness probe failed: Get http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:YYY/healthz: dial tcp connect: connection refused
```

---

Now coming to your real problem. The documentation that you provided clearly states in prerequisites section that you need to have a domain name and a DNS A record pointing to the DigitalOcean Load Balancer used by the Ingress (in your case you would want to point it towards `minikube`). Assuming you are the owner of the two domains you mentioned in the yamls I noticed that they points to a two different ip address:

```yaml
$ dig frontend.info
;; ANSWER SECTION:
frontend.info.          599     IN      A       104.247.81.51
```

```yaml
$ dig backend.info
;; ANSWER SECTION:
backend.info.           21599   IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

Domain has to point to  `external-ip` address of a machine where `minikube` is running (in my case it was cloud virtual machine). Having this, it is sill not enough since `minikube` typically runs in its own docker container or vm. You need to make sure the traffic actually reaches your minikube cluster.

For that purpose I have used `kubectl port-fowarding` to expose the `nginx-controller` pod:

```sh
sudo kubectl port-forward pod/ingress-nginx-controller-69ccf5d9d8-mdkrr -n kube-system 80:80 --address 0.0.0.0

Forwarding from 0.0.0.0:80 -> 80
```

Let's encrypt needs to have access to your application to prove that you are the owner of the domain.  Once this is achieved your certificate object will change it status to `True`:

```yaml
➜  ~ k get certificate                        
NAME       READY   SECRET     AGE
echo-tls   True    echo-tls   104m
```

Here you have final test. Please note that I was using my own domain which I just changed into `<your-domain>`. In your case this would `frontend.info` or `backend.info`

```java
➜  ~ curl https://<your-domain> -v         
-----
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=test-domain.com
*  start date: Jan 27 10:09:31 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 27 10:09:31 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "<your-domain>" matched cert's "<your-domain>"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
-----
```

Comment: My problem was not solved by changing to A name, but I think it is still a good point, there might be something missing on the config.

Answer (score 1):

I am also stuck there. But looking around, it seems that this website keeps popping up https://cert-manager.io/docs/faq/troubleshooting/

I am now trying to troubleshoot it myself. If I can fix it, I'll post the answer.